# Angularjs returns error Cannot set property 'subcomment_like' of undefined within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Am trying to to post and display/update content using angularjs within ng-repeat.

I was able to get the value of title displayed within

```
<div ng-repeat='post in posts'>
  {{ post.title }}
</div>
```

Now am trying to get a sub data within the first ng-repeat() function as in the case below but it returns error  **Cannot set property 'subcomment_like' of undefined within ng-repeat**

```
<div ng-repeat='post in posts'>

  {{ post.title }}
  <div ng-repeat='comment in post.comment'>

    {{comment.subcomment_like}}</div>
</div>
```

I have also tried

```
$scope.post.comment[index].subcomment_like = response.data[0].subcomment_like;
$scope.comment[index].subcomment_like = response.data[0].subcomment_like;
```

but with no luck. In console all the values are well displayed.

below is the code

```
<script>
  var fetch = angular.module('myapp', []);
  fetch.controller('fetchCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

        //initialize an arrays of commenting
        $scope.commenting = [];
        $scope.posts = [];

        $scope.setResponse = function(index, title, subcomment_like) {

          $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'content.php',
            data: {
              subcomment_like: subcomment_like,
              title: title
            }
          }).then(function successCallback(response) {

            $scope.posts[index].title = response.data[0].title;

            // Update total likes subcomment values on the post
            $scope.post.comment[index].subcomment_like = response.data[0].subcomment_like;


            $scope.commenting.push(response.data[0]);

          });
        }


      ]);
</script>


<div ng-repeat='post in posts'>

  {{ post.title }}

  <div ng-repeat='comment in post.comment'>

    {{comment.subcomment_like}}</div>
</div>
```

**//updated section for clarity**

In Your code `{{comment.subcomment_like}}` shows value of **1** from json in the angular view.   now am posting

```
data: {
              subcomment_like: 2
            }
```

All I want is to post `subcomment_like: 2` to replace already existing value of **1** for **subcomment_like** as displayed from json.

So that I can now have `{{comment.subcomment_like}}` shows value of **2** in the view/page after posting

Comment: can you post your array

Comment: [{"id":"1","title":"my first title.", "comment":[{"id":"359","subcomment_like":"1"}],

Comment: Please add a sample JSON of `$scope.posts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid, however when you have the correct JSON, it should work as follows,

> $scope.posts = [   {
>       "id": "1",
>       "title": "my first title.",
>       "comment": [
>         {
>           "id": "359",
>           "subcomment_like": "1"
>         }
>       ]   } ];

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('test',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.posts = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "my first title.",
    "comment": [
      {
        "id": "359",
        "subcomment_like": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<div ng-repeat='post in posts'>
  {{ post.title }}
  <div ng-repeat='comment in post.comment'>
  {{comment.subcomment_like}}
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**EDIT:**

Just update the JSON as follwos,

```
$scope.posts.[0].comment[0].subcomment_like = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your json is what I have on my own end and it sucessfully displayed data. Now as you can see from my post/code. I have value subcomment_like coming from an input form. All I want is to post the suncomment_like value from a form and have it update/replace the one already on the view(as displayed by the database). hence I this line of   code show shows the error above.   $scope.post.comment[index].subcomment_like = response.data[0].subcomment_like;
 please sir can you help me further

Comment: can you brifely explain?

Comment: All I want is to update/replace the subcomment_like values 1 already on the view with subcomment_like value eg. 2 coming from Post.  Okay, Am using your code above now as a case study which shows the value of  1 for subcomment_like. now I have a form  and from my code above am posting a  subcomment_like data with a value of 2. How will the value 2 coming from the form be posted to update/replace the value of  1 of subcomment_like already on the view as displayed by json files/database. I hope you understand it now.

Comment: Sorry bro i seriously do not understand. its good if you break your sentence. its like an essay

Comment: I have added clarification on the code posted above. please see the updated section of the post for clarifications. thanks. waiting for your reply

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172850/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-chinazaike).